# Ruby on Rails and HTML created websites

Tags: html, website-design, ruby-on-rails, web-services

My question is simply this:

If I use Dreamweaver to create the website layout, but I need to use Ruby on Rails software to create a webservice (SSH included) will the HTML and Ruby conflict with each other?

I'm not very knowledgeable on the subject, and any help is appreciated. Basically, I just want to have a website where I post images in a blog-like fashion, and then I will have my Windows 7 Phone pull these images and populate them in an app of mine.

Thanks for any help and insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They won't conflict because they work together. The code you create with Ruby on Rails will produce or be integrated with the HTML in your website that is created by Dreamweaver. The SSH portion of your application will bypass the HTML completely (didn't know you could do SSH with RoR).

Comment: Thank you very much for that response. Perhaps you can further it (or I can ask another question) -- After I integrate both, I plan on using Action Pack in order to get the APIs needed for my phone application to access the images from my website.  If you would happen to know, with using Action Pack and Ruby/Dreamweaver, will I be fine in having my phone gain the image data I need to dynamically populate a listbox in my application?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that. But the folks over at [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) do. They'll be more then happy to help you.